# Having trouble implementing Stormpath form Login/Authentication alongside REST oAuth authentication in the same application

Tags: java, rest, oauth, stormpath

We're using stormpath with Java & also trying to combine form Login with REST API authentication on the same application.

I've setup stormpath servlet plugin as described here https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/quickstart.html... This works very fine.

Now, on the same application, we have APIs where I've implemented oAuth authentication with stormpath see here http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/api-key-management/

The first request for an access-token works fine by sending `Basic Base64(keyId:keySecret)` in the request header and `grant_type = client_credentials` in the body. Access tokens are being returned nicely. However trying to authenticate subsequent requests with the header `Bearer <the-obtained-access-token>` does not even hit the application before 
returning the following json error message...

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "access_token is invalid."
}
```

This is confusing because I've set breakpoints all over the application and I'm pretty sure that the API request doesn't hit the anywhere within the application before stormpath kicks in and returns this error. And even if stormpath somehow intercepts the request before getting to the REST interface, this message doesn't make any sense to me because i'm certainly making the subsequent API calls with a valid access-token obtained from the first call to get access-token.

I have run out of ideas why this could be happening but i'm suspecting that it may have something to do with stormpath config especially with a combination
of form Login/Authentication for web views and oAuth Athentication for REST endpoints. With that said, here's what my stormpath.properties looks like. Hope this could help point at anything I may be doing wrong.

```
stormpath.application.href=https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/[app-id]
stormpath.web.filters.authr=com.app.security.AuthorizationFilter
stormpath.web.request.event.listener = com.app.security.AuthenticationListener

stormpath.web.uris./resources/**=anon
stormpath.web.uris./assets/**=anon
stormpath.web.uris./v1.0/**=anon
stormpath.web.uris./** = authc,authr
stormpath.web.uris./**/**=authc,authr
```

Help with this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be related to an incorrect request.

Is it possible for you to try this code in your app?:

```
 private boolean verify(String accessToken) throws OauthAuthenticationException {
     HttpRequest request = createRequestForOauth2AuthenticatedOperation(accessToken);
     AccessTokenResult result = Applications.oauthRequestAuthenticator(application)
        .authenticate(request);
     System.out.println(result.getAccount().getEmail() + " was successfully verified, you can allow your protect operation to continue");
     return true;
 }

 private HttpRequest createRequestForOauth2AuthenticatedOperation(String token) {
     try {
         Map<String, String[]> headers = new LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>();
         headers.put("Accept", new String[]{"application/json"});
         headers.put("Authorization", new String[]{"Bearer " + token});
         HttpRequest request = HttpRequests.method(HttpMethod.GET)
             .headers(headers)
             .build();
         return request;
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return null;
     }
 }
```

Comment: hi @jstack, I tried this and it works. But this hasn't really been the major issue... The major problem is that when the call is made externally from outside the program e.g from a REST client, execution doesn't proceed into the application. Stormpath just immediately returns that error... whereas in a different application that's composed of only REST APIs the similar requests from the same REST client hits the application without that error.

Comment: I think the problem resides in the filter chain not being properly configured. Rather than adding token support yourself, did you try using the token management solution provided by the Servlet Plugin itself? This will automatically configure the Filter chain properly. Please take a look at this section: http://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/http-request-authentication.html#token-authentication

Comment: I think this might be something stormpath would want to look at. Because in this particular App, once I disabled the servlet plugin that handles authentication for the web views, the API authentication started functioning properly... Essentially what it tells me is that stormpath's web and REST oAuth cannot currently function side-by-side in the same application.

Comment: Could you please let me know what are the actual Stormpath dependencies that you are importing in your project? Thanks

Comment: I'm using only the `stormpath-servlet-plugin` maven dependency which also auto-includes `stormpath-sdk-api`, `stormpath-sdk-httpclient`, and `stormpath-sdk-oauth`... Version no is 1.0.RC5.1

Comment: Could you please add the code of `AuthorizationFilter` in the original post? I'd like to see what it is trying to do. It would be great if you could push a reduced working version of you project into github so I can download and troubleshoot it....

Answer (score 1):

I've prepared an example that demonstrates oauth token creation as well as authorized access to protected pages using access tokens.

It builds off of the servlet example in the Stormpath SDK. The repo can be found here: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-java-oauth-servlet-sample

It demonstrates running a servlet application and having an out-of-band program get and use oauth tokens to access protected resources.

The core of the oauth part is in `TokenAuthTest.java`:

```
public class TokenAuthTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String command = System.getProperty("command");

        if (command == null || !("getToken".equals(command) || "getPage".equals(command))) {
            System.err.println("Must supply a command:");
            System.err.println("\t-Dcommand=getToken OR");
            System.err.println("\t-Dcommand=getPage OR");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if ("getToken".equals(command)) {
            getToken();
        } else {
            getPage();
        }
    }

    private static final String APP_URL = "http://localhost:8080";
    private static final String OAUTH_URI = "/oauth/token";
    private static final String PROTECTED_URI = "/dashboard";

    private static void getToken() throws Exception {
        String username = System.getProperty("username");
        String password = System.getProperty("password");

        if (username == null || password == null) {
            System.err.println("Must supply -Dusername=<username> -Dpassword=<password> on the command line");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        PostMethod method = new PostMethod(APP_URL + OAUTH_URI);

        method.setRequestHeader("Origin", APP_URL);
        method.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        method.addParameter("grant_type", "password");
        method.addParameter("username", username);
        method.addParameter("password", password);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.executeMethod(method);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
        String readLine;
        while(((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)) {
            System.out.println(readLine);
        }
    }

    private static void getPage() throws Exception {
        String token = System.getProperty("token");

        if (token == null) {
            System.err.println("Must supply -Dtoken=<access token> on the command line");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        GetMethod method = new GetMethod(APP_URL + PROTECTED_URI);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        System.out.println("Attempting to retrieve " + PROTECTED_URI + " without token...");

        int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);
        System.out.println("return code: " + returnCode);

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Attempting to retrieve " + PROTECTED_URI + " with token...");

        method.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);
        System.out.println("return code: " + returnCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @afitnerd the problem here isn't exactly addressed by this solution. Authenticating the access-token programmatically like you are doing in your example works fine. If only stormpath lets the REST calls get to the service handling authentication for the requested resource. But the problem is that access to resources handled by the servlets go through normally whereas those targeted at the REST endpoints never hit the application at all. Stormpath always returns the described error json even before the calls ever get to the requested resource URI

Comment: My Servlet Container is JBoss AS7 if this renders some help towards understanding this issue