# Does Stormpath SDK provide a way to build queries for the NOT condition?

Tags: java, stormpath

With the StormpathSDK you would usually build queries like this:

```
Groups.where(Groups.name().eqIgnoreCase("SIMPLE_ADMIN"))
```

***note:*** `Groups.name()` is a Typed Expression Factory e.g `StringExpressionFactory`

Now for dates, there exists a few Date expression methods, e.g;

```
<date-expression>.matches(String value)
<date-expression>.gt(Date value)
<date-expression>.lt(Date value)
<date-expression>.gte(Date value)
<date-expression>.lte(Date value)
<date-expression>.equals(Date value)
<date-expression>.in(Date begin, Date end)
<date-expression>.in(Date begin, Duration duration)
```

And for Strings there exists the following String expression methods;

```
<string-expression>.eqIgnoreCase(String value)
<string-expression>.startsWithIgnoreCase(String value)
<string-expression>.endsWithIgnoreCase(String value)
<string-expression>.containsIgnoreCase(String value)
```

Since these expressions do not return a Type that can be operated upon by e.g a boolean negator, **I find it quite odd that there's no comparison method to check for the NOT condition** e.g

```
<expression>.notEquals(...)
<expression>.notMatches(...)
<expression>.notContains(...)
<expression>.notIn(...)
```

Is there any known way to achieve what these type of methods should supposedly do?... Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If negation was possible, it would likely be available as as a modifier on the Typed ExpressionFactory, for example:

```
<date-expression>.not().matches(String value)
<date-expression>.not().gt(Date value)
<date-expression>.not().lt(Date value)
<date-expression>.not().gte(Date value)
<date-expression>.not().lte(Date value)
<date-expression>.not().equals(Date value)
<date-expression>.not().in(Date begin, Date end)
<date-expression>.not().in(Date begin, Duration duration)
```

However, this functionality does not exist in the Java SDK (or Stormpath's other SDKs) because the underlying REST API does not currently support negation in query criteria.

Comment: Thanks @Les_Hazlewood, is there any possibility that you guys would add any alternatives the Stormpath SDK that supports negation of queries.  If i'm not too forgetful, I think the JPA CriteriaQuery API has something similar

Comment: And knowing you're the CTO of Stormpath, could you please also help take a look at my question here?... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605873/having-trouble-implementing-stormpath-form-login-authentication-alongside-rest-o

Comment: @Tall'jeezzy not sure we can do anything at the SDK level for this - the underlying REST API itself has to support negation before our SDKs could utilize it.  We've noted this as a feature request for our API team though!

Comment: @Tall'jeezzy I'll see if our Java SDK team can help out!